# Git for visual studio 2015, delete intermediate commit

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

Im new using GIT...While working with it, i have created intermediate commits just in the case my computer crash or something like that, so i have a commit history like this in a new branch

```
frmClients - crud Operations final
frmClients - crud Operations tmp3
frmClients - crud Operations tmp2
frmClients - crud Operations tmp1
```

I would like to know if there is a way to delete those intermediate commits (from tmp1 to tmp3) and keep only the last one, i didnt merge&push it yet to the server.

Doing a revert or hard reset wont do what i want. Or mayb im using git in a wrong way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Squash my last X commits together using Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)

Answer (score 1):

[Rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) is your friend here:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

Replace the second to fourth lines starting with "pick" to "f" for "fixup", and you'll end up with a single commit.

Comment: Yeah mayb my question is duplicated, but ur answer helped me a lot to go for the right way and save time, since im new on git and i was lost on how to do this. thanks